# Reuse nested loops without copy and paste

Tags: c++, loops, macros, foreach, nested-loops

Suppose I've this nested loop

```
for (int a=1; a<MAX_A; ++a)
  for (int b=1; b<MAX_B; ++b)
    for (int c=1; c<MAX_C; ++c)
    {
       do_something(a, b ,c);
    }
```

and I reuse this loop in various part of my code, changing the function `do_something`. It's quite boring to rewrite every time the first three lines. In python for example I would created a generator to return an iterator `(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), ...` or something like `itertools.product`.

In c++ the only solution I've in mind is to define a macro. Something better?e

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use templates:

```
template<typename Func>
inline void do_something_loop(Func f)
{
    for (int a=1; a<MAX_A; ++a) 
      for (int b=1; b<MAX_B; ++b) 
        for (int c=1; c<MAX_C; ++c) 
        { 
           f(a, b ,c); 
        } 
}
```

This can be called with any function pointer or function object that matches the signature, e.g.:

```
void do_something(int a, int b, int c) { /* stuff */ }

do_something_loop(do_something);
```

Or with a function object:

```
struct do_something
{
    void operator()(int a, int b, int c) { /* stuff */ }
};

do_something_loop(do_something());
```

Or if your compiler supports C++11, even with a lambda:

```
do_something_loop([](int a, int b, int c) { /* stuff */ });
```

Note that you could also declare the `f` parameter as a function pointer with the signature `void(*f)(int,int,int)` instead of using a template, but that's less flexible (it won't work on function objects (including the result of std::bind) or lambdas).

Comment: This is ok, but I need to define a function every time (no c++11). The advantages of macro is that I can write stuff like: `MYLOOP_BEGIN { v[a] = 10; vv[a][b][c] = a+1; } MYLOOP_END;`

Comment: Yes, without lambdas there is no way other than a macro to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Make a helper loop function:

```
template<typename Work>
void loop(Work work) {
  for (int a=1; a<MAX_A; ++a)
    for (int b=1; b<MAX_B; ++b)
      for (int c=1; c<MAX_C; ++c)
      {
        work(a, b ,c);
      }
}
```

Define the work to be done:

```
void some_work(int a, int b, int c) {
}
```

Then use:

```
loop(some_work);
```

Note that now you don't need to use only function, but you can use a function object (object for which an `operator()` is overloaded).

Comment: 1/ `do` is a keyword (the specter of untested code...) 2/ The `&` before `some_work` is unneeded in C++, a function reference is trivially convertible into a function pointer.