# Reusing PHP nested loop structure for multiple purposes

Tags: php

I have a nested loop to iterate over a data structure comprised of different object types. I would like to use this loop structure for multiple purposes.

I found a discussion about [how to reuse nested loops in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158518/reuse-nested-loops-without-copy-and-paste). Is there a way in PHP to reuse this loop structure without copying the loop into a new function for each different case?

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($this->orders as $order) { // OrderObject
foreach ($order->items as $itemGroup) { // ItemPrice, ItemFees
    foreach ($itemGroup as $item) { // PrincipalItem, PriceItem, FeeItem
        switch (get_class($item)) {
            case 'PrincipalItem':
                $revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax() * $item->quantity;
                break;
            case 'PriceItem':
                $revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax();
                break;
            case 'FeeItem':
                $fees += $item->amount;
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the first instance above, I am summing various values. In another instance, I would like to output data as a CSV. The same loop will accomplish this, I just need to change the lines inside the switch cases.

Comment: anonymous functions maybe? just pass an instance of `$this` into it when you want to use it

Comment: Isn't that what `functions` are for?

Comment: @nytrix Can you explain further?

Comment: @iakkam refer to my answer below.

Comment: I want to be able to use this loop structure but change which statements get executed inside. For example, `$revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax() * $item->quantity;` could become `$this->convert2CSV($item);` I want to reuse the loop in performing various functions on the data.

Comment: What's the benefit of "reusing" three nested loops? During the time you spent writing this question, reading the comments and answers you can write the three nested loops hundreds of times. If you want to improve something then think how easy is for another developer to understand the code you write. Is it easier or harder to understand the purpose of the nested loops if you create a function out of them? I think it is harder. The flow of the three nested loops already is difficult to understand.

Comment: @axiac I'm an amateur programmer so I wanted to know whether there are advanced techniques I can use in this situation. For example, I know there are such structures as Iterators and perhaps an Iterator could be useful in this case. Secondly, if you think three nested loops is difficult to understand, please suggest a better way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `switch (get_class($item))` part of your code is an incorrect implementation of the OOP concept called [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping).

The correct way to do it is to define an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) that declares a method (let's name it `updateAmounts()`) then implement the interface in all classes you can have as `$item` in the inner loop. Each implementation of the `updateAmounts()` method contains the code from corresponding `case` of the `switch` statement.

Something like this:

```
// This class is a Value Object.
// It doesn't need behaviour and it's OK to have public properties
class Amounts
{
    public $revenue = 0;
    public $fees    = 0;
}

interface HasAmounts
{
    /**
     * Update the revenue and the fees in the passed Amounts object
     * using the data stored in this object.
     */
    public function updateAmounts(Amounts $a);
}

class PrincipalItem implements HasAmounts
{
    public function updateAmounts(Amounts $a)
    {
        $a->revenue += $this->getAmountAfterTax() * $this->quantity;
    }
}

class PriceItem implements HasAmounts
{
    public function updateAmounts(Amounts $a)
    {
        $a->revenue += $this->getAmountAfterTax();
    }
}

class FeeItem implements HasAmounts
{
    public function updateAmounts(Amounts $a)
    {
        $a->fees += $this->amount;
    }
}
```

Now the nested loops look like this:

```
$amounts = new Amounts();
foreach ($this->orders as $order) { // OrderObject
    foreach ($order->items as $itemGroup) { // ItemPrice, ItemFees
        foreach ($itemGroup as $item) { // PrincipalItem, PriceItem, FeeItem
            $item->updateAmounts($amounts);
        }
    }
}
echo('Revenue: '.$amounts->revenue."\n");
echo('Fees: '.$amounts->fees."\n");
```

If the classes `PrincipalItem`, `PriceItem` and `FeeItem` already extend the same base class (or have a common ancestor) then the method can be added (as [`abstract`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) or with an empty implementation) to this class (and the interface is not needed any more).

---

After the above transformation of the code, do you still want to find a way to reuse the nested `foreach` block?

The `foreach` statements don't look worth reusing now. This happens because the code that is worth reusing was moved where it belongs; the code should stay together with the data it handles, in the class.

Further refactoring can be operated on the code by moving each `foreach` in the class that contains the data it operates on.

For example:

```
class OrderObject implements HasAmounts
{
    public function updateAmounts(Amounts $a)
    {
        foreach ($this->items as $itemGroup) { // ItemPrice, ItemFees
            foreach ($itemGroup as $item) { // PrincipalItem, PriceItem, FeeItem
                $item->updateAmounts($amounts);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If `$itemGroup` is an object of some class (or more) then the inner `foreach` can be moved to each of these classes (in its implementation of the `updateAmounts()` method) and this way the code stays in the same class with the data it processes (it's called [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Encapsulation) and it is another important property of the OOP code).

Now the calling code now looks like this:

```
$amounts = new Amounts();
foreach ($this->orders as $order) { // OrderObject
    $order->updateAmounts($amounts);
}
echo('Revenue: '.$amounts->revenue."\n");
echo('Fees: '.$amounts->fees."\n");
```

***Look, ma! No more nested `foreach` loops***

I'm afraid I tore apart your pack of nested `foreach` loops and there is nothing to reuse from it.

But wait! Your classes now contain behaviour (they probably used to be just amorphous containers of data) and this is better than writing all-purpose code (as it seems it was your goal of reusing the `foreach` loops). Because this is what OOP is supposed to be: data and code packed together.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I learned a lot. I'm sorry for the delay in replying ... I was actually thinking about it and didn't have time until now to fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

In case that you want to use a certain piece of code multiple time, you make `functions`. Those can then be executed. Here is the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) on functions.

*Example:*

```
<?php
function example($itemGroup,$orders,$items){

    foreach ($orders as $order) { // OrderObject
        foreach ($items as $itemGroup) { // ItemPrice, ItemFees
            foreach ($itemGroup as $item) { // PrincipalItem, PriceItem, FeeItem
                switch (get_class($item)) {
                    case 'PrincipalItem':
                        $revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax() * $item->quantity;
                        break;
                    case 'PriceItem':
                        $revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax();
                        break;
                    case 'FeeItem':
                        $fees += $item->amount;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

example($value,$oders,$items);
?>
```

You can now call this `example` anywhere. In case you are writing in `OOP` please refer to the manual.

As mentioned before, you can also store `functions` in a `variable`, those are called `Anonymous functions`. Here is the reference to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

*Example*

```
<?php   
$var = function($variable){
    echo "this is a function with a ".$variable;
}

$var("variable");
?>
```

You can call those functions like showed in the code.

All this leads to your actuall answer, you can fuse those together, like so.

*Example*

```
<?php

function test( callable $function){
    $function();
}

test(function(){
    echo "some code";
})

?>
```

*In your case:*

```
<?php
function example($itemGroup,$orders,$items,$function()){

    foreach ($orders as $order) { // OrderObject
        foreach ($items as $itemGroup) { // ItemPrice, ItemFees
            foreach ($itemGroup as $item) { // PrincipalItem, PriceItem, FeeItem
                $function();
            }
        }
    }

}

example($itemGroup,$orders,$items,function(){

    switch (get_class($item)) {
        case 'PrincipalItem':
            $revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax() * $item->quantity;
            break;
        case 'PriceItem':
            $revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax();
            break;
        case 'FeeItem':
            $fees += $item->amount;
            break;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand functions, but I'm not sure this answer helps. Your function contains my nested loop but retains the lines inside the switch/case statements that I'd like to change depending on my purpose. The lines I'd like to change are ones like `$revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax() * $item->quantity;`

Comment: @iakkam your question was how to repeat a certain piece of code. I gave you the answer. What is it you want to change then?

Comment: I want to reuse the loop but execute different statements inside the switch/case ... for example, `$revenue += $item->getAmountAfterTax() * $item->quantity;` could become something totally different like `$this->convert2CSV($item);`

Comment: @iakkam has this solved your problem or not? I have tested this method and it works fine for me.