# Editing list inside template not saving

Tags: c++, list, function, templates, for-loop

I have a for loop that I want to use multiple times without copy and pasting the code so I'm using a template. [Answer I used for the template.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158518/reuse-nested-loops-without-copy-and-paste)
The template and loop itself work as intended, but changing a variable from the list inside the function called inside the for loop doesn't work.
If I change s.Color inside the 'Test' function, it has not changed outside of that function or the example loop.

**So why it is not changed outside of the loop? And how can I make sure it changes outside of the loop?**

Template:

```
void Test(TrafficLight s) {
    switch (s.Type) {
    case hfdWeg:
        s.Color = queueCurrent.HoofdwegColor;
        break;
    case zWeg:
        s.Color = queueCurrent.ZijwegColor;
        break;
    case vtPad:
        s.Color = queueCurrent.VoetpadColor;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "\nError";
        break;
    }
}

template<typename Func>
inline void do_something_loop(Func f)
{
    for (std::list<TrafficLight>::iterator i = Lichten.begin(); i !=    Lichten.end(); ++i) {
        TrafficLight & s(*i);
        f(s);
    }
}
```

Calling the template:

```
do_something_loop(Test);
```

The list:

```
std::list<TrafficLight> Lichten;
```

TrafficLight class:

```
class TrafficLight {
private:
public:
    TrafficLight(TrafficLightType type, TrafficLightColor color = R) {
        Color = color;
        Type = type;
    }
    TrafficLightColor Color;
    TrafficLightType Type;
};
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the temporary variable `s` is not needed in the loop. You can just pass `*i` directly. Or use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) instead of an explicit loop (or use it instead of your function even).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Wasn't sure if that was possible and forgot to test that, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose:

```
void Test(TrafficLight s) { ... }
```

should be:

```
void Test(TrafficLight& s) { ... }
```

because now you edit a copy.

So need to pass *by reference* instead.

Comment: Wow, much easier to solve than I thought. What exactly does the & mean here?

Comment: @TeunissenStefan it means that you pass `TrafficLight` object *by reference* so you could edit an actual object inside `Test` function.

Comment: So if I called the function without using a template I should use the & as well?

Comment: @TeunissenStefan It seems you could use [a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This is very basic stuff.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude while that would be the most logical thing to do, I can't learn by just reading. For some reason my mind only learns when I do things and make mistakes.

Comment: @TeunissenStefan no matter whether you deal with templates or not. Just try to understand the difference between passing objects *by value* and *by reference* - that is the key. Passing by value you edit a copy of object, not the actual object. Passing by reference you edit the object itself.

Comment: @TeunissenStefan also consider accepting answer which helped you solve the issue...

Comment: @W.F. Calm down please. When I wanted to accept it I had to wait a few minutes. Went to the toilet and came back to this reply.

Comment: @TeunissenStefan hah first time I was killed by the toilet :)

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
void Test(TrafficLight s)
```

to this:

```
void Test(TrafficLight& s)
```

since you need to pass by reference in order for the changes to persist after the function is terminated.

Your code passes the argument by value (it creates a *copy* of `s` inside th body of `Test()`).